# cakephp 3.6 fetching related data from database

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I am new with CakePHP and something is not working as expected.

I have a PostsController with the following method:

```
public function index()
{
    $posts = $this->Posts->find('all');
    $this->set(compact('posts');
}
```

But if I try to fetch data from another table/model like:

```
public function index()
{
    $posts = $this->Posts->find('all');
    $categories = $this->Categories->find('all');

    $this->set(compact('posts', 'categories');
}
```

This will give me the following error:

> Call to a member function find() on boolean

What am I missing?

I am using CakePHP version 3.6.3

Answer (score 1):

In PostsController only Posts Model is loaded, you have to load Categories model too.

```
public function index()
{
    $posts = $this->Posts->find('all');
    $categories = $this->loadModel('Categories')->find('all');

    $this->set(compact('posts', 'categories');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `PostsController`, `$this->Posts` is automagically initialized, but `$this->Categories` is not. Assuming that Posts and Categories are associated, you could use `$this->Posts->Categories->find()`. If not, you could use `TableRegistry::get('Categories')->find()`.